# Derivative of $\sin(\theta)$ Query

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Quick query...

If we let 
$$ t = \sin(\theta) $$

then we have

$$ dt = \cos(\theta) d\theta = \sqrt{1 - t^2} d\theta $$

Now, I get the

$$ dt = \cos(\theta) d\theta $$

Part, as

$$ \frac{d}{d\theta}\sin(\theta) = \cos(\theta) $$

Where does the

$$ \frac{d}{d\theta}\sin(\theta) = \sqrt{1 - t^2} $$

Come from?

What am I not getting here?

Thankyou for any advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It comes from the fact that 
$$ \sin^2 \theta +\cos^2 \theta =1 $$
Therefore 
$$ \cos^2 \theta =1 -\sin^2 \theta $$
$$ \cos \theta =\pm\sqrt{1 -\sin^2 \theta}$$
Where the sign is dependent on the quadrant of $\theta$
$$ \frac{d}{d\theta}\sin\theta= \cos \theta =\pm\sqrt{1 -\sin^2 \theta}$$
Since $t=\sin\theta$, then we have
$$ \frac{d}{d\theta}t= \cos \theta =\pm\sqrt{1 -t^2}$$

Comment: Ahh ok.  Thats what threw me.  Plotting the two functions within Mathcad gave me an inversion of the $ \sqrt{1-\sin^2(\theta)} $ function, which to my mind means that $ \cos(\theta) <> \sqrt{1-\sin^2(\theta)} $  Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @MikeShaw, anytime. Glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{align}\cos\theta &= \sqrt{1-\sin^2\theta}
\\&= \sqrt{1-t^2} \qquad \text{because }t = \sin\theta\end{align}$$